# Request: Add lang-rust language code for posts tagged rust

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Prettify already supports Rust, and [this documentation post on language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) explicitly lists `lang-rust` as a valid identifier. Could we get the Rust tag associated with the `lang-rust` identifier?